В google play console получаю предупреждения об удалении аккаунта из-за того, что аккаунт не подтвержден
В google play console в личном кабинете требуют от меня подтвердить способ оплаты продавца или "Ваш профиль разработчика и все ваши приложения будут удалены из Google Play""
Перепробовал много карт разных банков, ни одна не привязывается, так как проживаю в России
и свифт у нас не работает.
Обращался в поддержку, они просто сочувствуют и ничем не могут помочь.

Сейчас многие российские банки предлагают сделать карту зарубежного банка (казахского, турецкого и т.д.), но стоит это дорого и не факт, что эти карты тоже в любой момент не отрубят. Но на крайний случай есть такая опция, можно её попробовать.

Например, какие, что-то нее могу найти, и еще, у меня нет загранпаспорта.

Примеры: https://www.rosbank.ru/premialnoe-obsluzhivanie/debetovye-karty/karta-inostrannogo-banka/ https://www.vbr.ru/banki/novosti/2023/03/14/oformit-zarybejnyu-karty/ https://quote.rbc.ru/news/article/626c1cf59a7947163cd62317

Зачем вам консоль Google Play, если вы даже не можете получить с них денег? Пользуйтесь F-Droid или Рустор

Кстати говоря, угрозы не из-за того, что вы проживаете в России

что за бред укушенного, только с покупок получают деньги? здесь идет речь про конкретную площадку. и да, я проживаю в России поэтому для меня это проблема выглядит как угроза

@Anatolii удалось ли решить проблему? Такая же беда

@Ильин Павел, да удалось решить, изменил вопрос сразу с решением.

Райфайзен тоже вроде уходит из России, так что решение скорее всего уже не рабочее. Ну или доллары перестаёт переводить. В общем, это окошко тоже закрывается.

Решено!
Можно получить карту Райффайзенбанка и открыть долларовый счет, затем привязать его. Если есть какие-то доллары на счете, вам отправит их Google, но банк возьмет комиссию огромную до 100%.Нужно просто написать в поддержку, что не знали что такая высокая комиссия и вам в первый раз вернут ее.
Второй способ не пробовал, но пишут что рабочий, это пройти процедуру определения лица через Сбер на госуслуги и открыть удаленно счет в Челябинвестбанк. Там комиссия минимальна.

Вот, я как раз попробовал вторым способом — завел счет в Челябинвестбанке и попытался зарегистрировать этот счет как основной платежный способ. Именно после этого я и получил уведомление о том, что мой аккаунт будет вскоре удален.
Подскажите, когда вы регистрировали счет в Райффазене как основной способ оплаты, Google запрашивал у вас выписку по счету и/или фото паспорта?
У меня запрашивает и то, и то (регистрирую счет опять таки из Челябинвестбанка), но проверка не проходит. Пытаюсь уже раз 7 или 8.

В Райффайзен в мобильном приложении я открыл долларовый счет. Выписку Google запрашивал,там есть кнопка в мобильном приложении когда заходишь в долларовый счет - выгрузить выписку по счету, его  отправил, и все прошгло успешно. Фото паспорта спрашивал Google, но я его уже давно отправил, там проблем не было. 13 августа зарегистрировал как основной счет Райффайзен в Google

Мне удалось подтвердить платежный профиль с помощью Челябинвестбанк

Ильин Павел, классно, я его тоже привяжу вместо Райффайзена как основной, потому что там комиссия минимальна.

Все ещё работает? тут на страничке банка говорят что входящие переводы в долларах не пройдут https://chelinvest.ru/news/izmeneniya-v-poryadke-osushchestvleniya-perevodov-po-sisteme-swift/ какие ещё варианты есть?

@Sergey сообщение, на которое вы ссылаетесь, было написано задолго до того, как было применено решение из темы. Деньги были выведены в долларах и все было нормально
